# How should I edit my code to produce a particular type of image?

Tags: plotting

I drew this tapered prolate spheroid in Mathematica as a 3D contour plot:

```
ContourPlot3D[
  (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 == 1.2 x^3 + 0.36 x 
  (y^2 + z^2), {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

However, I am *quite* inexperienced in programming with Mathematica, and I am trying to make it look like this:

[image]

At least roughly. Preferably the color scheme, aspect ratio, and general outline could be the same -- the axes would be nice but I understand that this may not be possible.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
ContourPlot3D[
  (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 == 1.2 x^3 + 0.36 x (y^2 + z^2), 
  {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][z]], 
  Mesh -> 4,
  Boxed -> False, 
  Axes->False, 
  Lighting->"Neutral", 
  ImageSize->Large]`
```

Which makes little progress.

Also, slightly unrelated, but when I double click (or click to rotate) on the image produced by the above code, the image becomes quite vivid and clear. How do I save *this* version of the image, instead of the 'dulled' default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some analysis that I performed to get a explicit plot rather than an implicit one.

```
Solve[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 == 120/100 x^3 + 36/100 x (y^2 + z^2), z, Reals]
```

This gives

[image: solutions]

The 2nd conditional solution is clearly the one giving the top side of the egg-shaped surface you are considering. Therefore, a normal 3D plot of the expression

```
Sqrt[(1/50) Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 x^2 + 700 x^3] + (1/50) (9 x - 50 x^2 - 50 y^2)]
```

should be pursued. It also clear the x-range of plot should be `{x, 0, 6/5}`. The surface is symmetrical about the x-axis, so the y-range will be `{y, -ymax, ymax}` and `ymax` can determined by first evaluating

```
Reduce[
  0 < x < 6/5 && 
    Sqrt[2] Sqrt[9 x - 50 x^2 + Sqrt[3] Sqrt[x^2 (27 + 700 x)]] - 10 y > 0, 
  y]
```

> ```
> 0 < x < 6/5 && y < Root[-30 x^3 + 25 x^4 + (-9 x + 50 x^2) #1^2 + 25 #1^4&, 2]
> ```

and then

```
FindMaximum[Root[-30 x^3 + 25 x^4 + (-9 x + 50 x^2) #1^2 + 25 #1^4 &, 2], x]
```

> ```
> {0.43456, {x -> 0.649557}}
> ```

This suggests that `{y, -1/2, 1/2}` will work for the y-range.

Using the results of my little analysis, I made the following plot:

```
Plot3D[
  Sqrt[(1/50) Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 x^2 + 700 x^3] + (1/50) (9 x - 50 x^2 - 50 y^2)],
  {x, 0, 6/5}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][z]],
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.92],
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/3},
  Mesh -> None,
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> False,
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: plot]

This is certainly closer to the plot you show than the plot your code produces. The question I have is: it is close enough for this post to answer your question?

#### Update

This update address an issue raised by the OP in a comment to this question.

Here is how to add the lines you ask for. The numbers that determine the end points of the lines come from the analysis given above.

```
surface =
  Plot3D[
    Sqrt[(1/50) Sqrt[3] Sqrt[27 x^2 + 700 x^3] + (1/50) (9 x - 50 x^2 - 50 y^2)],
    {x, 0, 6/5}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}, 
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][z]],
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.92],
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    BoxRatios -> {1, 2*0.43456, .43456},
    Mesh -> None,
    Boxed -> False,
    Axes -> False,
    SphericalRegion -> True,
    Lighting -> "Neutral",
    ImageSize -> 500];

lines = 
  Graphics3D[
    {AbsoluteThickness[4], CapForm[None],
     Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.2, 0, 0}}], 
     Line[{{.649557, -.43456, 0}, {.649557, .43456, 0}}], 
     Line[{{.649557, 0, 0}, {.649557, .0, .43456}}]}];

Show[surface, lines]
```

[image: plot]

The following views make it evident that the surface is the top half of an egg-shaped surface and not an ellipsoid.

top view

[image: top]

front veiw

[image: front]

Comment: Quite amazing! Thank you immensely! However, I need to show that the major axis is a length of 1.2 and the y axis is (if I recall correctly) 0.84. Is there a way we can add these two lengths as axes?

Comment: @Equinox. My analysis shows that length of the shape along the x-axis is 6/5 = 1.2. It also shows the maximum width perpendicular to x-axis is 2 * .43456 = .86912, not .84. The surface is not ellipsoidal -- it is slightly egg-shaped. It doesn't really have a semi-major axis

Comment: Sorry, the length is 1.2 and the perpendicular at the highest point is .43. Is there a way we could show this?

Comment: @Equinox. I have updated my answer to show how the lines can be added.

Comment: Yay, perfect. Do you know why a double-click and try-to-move with on the figure changes the image resolution?

Comment: @Equinox. No, but I find it just as annoying as you do.

Comment: I think that if you press and drag slightly, but then simultaneously right-click, the save-as shows up and you move over it and release the mouse. This works to save it in the higher resolution.